# additional condition for sql query

Tags: sql, sqlite

It is necessary to select groups whose students took part in all competitions. I made such a request. But the condition falls under it when there is only one such student in the group. You need two or more.

```
CREATE VIEW V3 AS
SELECT Groups
FROM R3
JOIN R1 USING (name)
GROUP BY Groups
HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT Competition) = (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT Competition) FROM R1);
```

Tables

```
CREATE TABLE R1(
name VARCHAR(100),
article VARCHAR(100),
Competition VARCHAR(100));

CREATE TABLE R3 (
name VARCHAR(100),
Groups VARCHAR(100)
);
```

I tried adding the condition COUNT (DISTINCT Groups) > 1 but it not work

Comment: There is no way your query is even running without errors, as `GROUP` is a reserved SQL keyword.  Please post the actual query.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions. Note that homework related questions are expected to prove some extra effort.

Comment: The word is translated from another language
it is not registered

Comment: Still very confusing for the rest of us.

Comment: What exactly ???

Comment: we just need to output groups with two or more such students

Comment: Move the subquery which counts total competitions amount to FROM clause (CROSS JOIN).

Comment: Please write a request as you suggest

Comment: Please tag your database

Answer (score 0):

This is one way:

```
with cte as (select r1.name, Groups_c, count(r1.name) over(partition by Groups_c) cnt2
from r1
left join r3 on r1.name = r3.name
group by  r3.name,  Groups_c
having count(distinct Competition) = (select count(distinct Competition) from r1))
select r3.Groups_c
from r3
left join cte on r3.Groups_c = cte.Groups_c
group by r3.Groups_c
having count (distinct r3.name) = cte.cnt2
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=0fd7966dca2fb5d952859b36b324b140)

Comment: Hi @Bukashka is the answer working ok ?